# Set SNMP value for custom OID

Tags: c#, windows, snmp

We have [applied](http://pen.iana.org/pen/PenApplication.page) for a [Private Enterprise Number](http://www.iana.org/assignments/enterprise-numbers) to "reserve" a space in the SNMP MIB "tree" to store some monitoring values. We will, eventually, be assigned a number like:

```
iso.org.dod.internet.private.enterprise.XXX (1.3.6.1.4.1.XXX)
```

We haven't received our allotted PEN yet, but I was hoping to get my project started by simply taking a (temporary, only on my workstation) OID and writing a value to it using [SNMP#Net](http://www.snmpsharpnet.com/).  I have followed the [set example](http://www.snmpsharpnet.com/content/how-make-snmp-set-request) which works fine (the `sysLocation`, OID `1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0`, is set fine).

So, next I tried setting a "faked" OID (`1.3.6.1.4.1.99999.1.0`, where `99999` would, eventually, become our allotted PEN). This, however, fails with `ErrorStatus 17`, which, according to [this source](http://www.snmpsharpnet.com/content/how-make-snmp-set-request), should be "The variable cannot be written or created."

I have checked my SNMP Agent service and the `private` community which I'm using is set to `READ/CREATE`. I am using C# on Windows 7.

Is there something I need to do before I can set my desired value? Do I need to import some kind of "MIB definition" before windows allows me to set a value? What would I need to do in order to (for now test) set values? Maybe I need to "declare" or "register" my desired OID first with the SNMP agent?

Comment: Have you tried the same code with a real, existing OID?

Comment: I did, it is mentioned in my question: "I have followed the set example which works fine (the sysLocation, OID 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0, is set fine)."

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part on the first read. Odd. Have you tried another "fake" OID with a less extreme value, e.g. `1337` or `999`? I assume you have written a MIB?

Comment: Yes, I tried `999` coincidally and also, for example, just `1`. But, as the [current largest PEN](http://www.iana.org/assignments/enterprise-numbers) is `40238` I think `99999` should be no problem.

Comment: What SNMP service are you making requests to? If the service doesn't know about the OID, it can't do anything with the request.

Comment: I am doing a `set` request; I want to 'store' (or register) my own value(s) in the SNMP agent. The next step would be something like Nagios reading these values but that is step 2. Because I'm doing a `set` I am, kind of, assuming the OID ("path") would be created/set by the SNMP agent when unknown? That is why my question is: "Is there something I need to do before I can set my desired value?" The request is sent to the "standard" SNMP Agent service on Windows. All this information is, by the way, right there in the question.

Comment: The SNMP agent needs to know about the OID and have some form of provider before it can handle the request. In Windows, I believe you can create a WMI provider that supplies SNMP information, but I've never tried it.

Comment: Again, it's right there in the question: "Do I need to import some kind of "MIB definition" before windows allows me to set a value?". **How** do I tell the SNMP agent about the OID and how would I apply that to [this example](http://www.snmpsharpnet.com/content/how-make-snmp-set-request)?

Comment: Ah, now I understand the question. Sorry, my brain's not quite awake yet.

Comment: No problem. I have the same problem too sometimes. Have a coffee and then tell me the solution :P ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register the variable in the SNMP Agent provider service as part of a binding list, using the [WinSNMP API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379207.aspx).

Essentially you use `SnmpCreateVbl` to bind an OID to a variable.

Comment: Any idea *if* that could be done with [SNMP#Net](http://www.snmpsharpnet.com) and if so, *how*? I can't find it in the [examples](http://www.snmpsharpnet.com/node/9) nor the "[documentation](http://www.docs.snmpsharpnet.com/current/index.html)". Also, what would be the correct term for this? "Register SNMP agent"? That would help my google-searches.

Comment: SNMP#Net is a client library, not an agent library. It's designed to talk to SNMP agents. As such, it doesn't support that. You'll need to look at the examples on MSDN for WinSNMP and translate them to C#. You'll need to PInvoke the APIs.

Comment: Yeah, it's beginning to dawn on me now. I'll have to look into it a bit better... Thanks for the help so far.